# Incompatible return type for subclasses in "Requirements in Overriding and Hiding" of JLS

Tags: java, jls

quoting from JLS

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the
>   declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be
>   return-type substitutable for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.
>   **Furthermore, if R1 is not a subtype of R2, an unchecked warning must
>   be issued (unless suppressed (§9.6.1.5)).** A method declaration must
>   not have a throws clause that conflicts (§8.4.6) with that of any
>   method that it overrides or hides; otherwise, a compile-time error
>   occurs.

Doesn't the bold sentence contradict the first part of the paragraph.

I can read below in JLS that this applies for generic returns for example

`List<String>` return type being overrided by `List` return type but still that sentence in the JLS doesn't exclude this to only this situation, can you clarify me if there is another situation where that sentence applies?

Comment: Is it possible that two objects that both implement the same interface but one is not a subtype of another could qualify as "return-type substitutable"?  (Just a shot in the dark.)

Comment: I think that the return-type substitutable has to be a "is-a" in relation to the superclass method return type, so if the superclass method has the interface as return type, any of the two objects would apply for the return type in the subclass method